# How to manage data table using global variable in Power Apps

Tags: office365, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, power-platform

I have created a Data table using global variable in my app. Now, I want to display the perticular records (Office Chair Details) in other blank screen:

[image]

And, before my code is:

```
OnStart = Set(
    gvProducts,
    Table(
        {
            ProductName: "Office Chair",
            Price: 1500,
            Category: "Office",
            Quantity: 5,
            Color: "Brown"
        },
        {
            ProductName: "Dining Tabel",
            Price: 1000,
            Category: "Home",
            Quantity: 10,
            Color: "Red"
        },
        {
            ProductName: "
Lawn & Garden Accessories",
            Price: 1900,
            Category: "Outdoor",
            Quantity: 30,
            Color: "Green"
        },
        {
            ProductName: "Baby Furniture",
            Price: 900,
            Category: "Children",
            Quantity: 15,
            Color: "Blue"
        },
        {
            ProductName: "
Bowls and Feeders",
            Price: 1000,
            Category: "Pet Furniture",
            Quantity: 25,
            Color: "White"
        }
    )
)
```

Please, suggest any solution.

I want to display the specific record values in other screen.

Comment: When you want to navigate to other blank screen and show the details? For example when clicking on the row in table or when clicking on any particular icon/button from main screen where you have shown data table?

Comment: Like a particular row of the record and only we will get that record details only...

Comment: That I understood from the original post. But, when do you want to show the records details? What will be the user action for that, like any button click or on click of whole row/record?

Comment: using button click

Comment: Where do you have the button, inside datatable or outside datatable? I don't see any button in the image you provided.

Comment: The right corner of the row (Inside)

Comment: Can you show us how you added the button inside data table? Is this button available for each row in the data table?

Comment: Sorry inside it is not possible

Comment: Hi @GaneshM, Did you try my solution given below? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Add one new blank screen and name it `DetailsScreen`.
2. Select all the columns inside your data table and set `OnSelect` property to:

   ```
   Navigate(DetailsScreen)
   ```

   [image]
3. Insert label controls on the `DetailsScreen` and set the `Text` property of label controls to show the product details like below:

   For example: Set below formula for `Text` property of label control to show the product name:

   ```
   DataTable1.Selected.ProductName
   ```

   [image]

Similarly, you can add more label controls on the `DetailsScreen` to show the other product details (like I have show product category using the formula: `DataTable1.Selected.Category`).

Where `DataTable1` is the name of your data table control in the Power Apps.